# How do you find percentage of a padding that's in pixels?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I'v been trying to find an answer to this question on the internet but couldn't find anything that explained it well. I'm still confused and have no idea how to figure out the percentage of a padding that's in pixels. For example i'm looking at a website design and I know that an `<h1>` needs a `10px` padding on top, but how do I figure out what the padding is in percentage?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: 100% will be the size of the full height in pixels. 10% will be 10 percent of that. So if your h1 is 50px, 10% padding-top will be 5px;

Comment: Of which value should the padding be a percentage? The browser width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the difference between PX, EM and Percent?**

> Pixel is a static measurement, while percent and EM are relative measurements. The size of an EM or percent depends on its parent. If the text size of body is 16 pixels, then 150% or 1.5 EM will be 24 pixels (1.5 * 16). Look at [CSS Units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) for more measurement units.

You've asked about `10px` padding on top of `h1`:

You know that the height in pixels is `100%`. So `10%` will be `10` percent of that. If your `h1` is `50px`, `10%` `padding-top` will be `5px`.

Comment: what do you mean "if your h1 is 50px"? are you talking about font size of h1?

Comment: For example, there could be a `line-height` associated with `h1`. You'd need to know that before assuming what the height of `h1` is.

Comment: I know that my 'h1' has the default line height, and I'm not sure how many px that is. Sorry if i'm not understanding something.